# Динамическое применение стиля к селекторам, у которых нет метода setStyle()

Tags: javafx

Через css-файл применяется стиль, например:

```
.chart-series-line{
-fx-stroke-width: 2;
}
```

А как тоже самое сделать через метод setStyle() в самом коде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```
for ( Node n : chart.lookupAll( ".chart-series-line" ) ) {
    n.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width: 2" );
}
```